# Trying to update attribute result in mass-update [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to change a value in my DB for a single item, I use first() to get an item, but for some reason when I try this function, every entry with the same primary key has the authenticated user gets the attribute 'AreFriend' updated at 1, why?

```
public function acceptrequest($id)
{
     $user = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user();
     if (!$targetuser = User::find($id)) {
         return response()->json(['status' => "The requested resource does not exists!"], 403);
     }
     if ($relation = $user->requestspending()->where('user_id', $targetuser->user_id)->first()) {
         Friend::unguard();
         $relation->AreFriend = 1;
         $relation->save();
         Friend::unguard();
         Friend::reguard();
         return response()->json(['status' => "Request accepted!"], 200);
     } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => "You do not have an invitation from this user!"], 403);
     }
}
```

In my database, relations with the $user id are updated. The variable $relation is an item, not a collection.

Comment: `$user->requestspending()->where('user_id', $targetuser->user_id)->first()` Already does this. I get the relation just fine, it's just when I try to change an attribute of $relation it updates everything.

Comment: What's the output for `dd($relation);` ?

Comment: Although, how do you call the `acceptrequest()` function ? (missing camelCase in that function name)

Comment: It returns a App\Http\Classes\Friend model and I get the right relation, I call funciton from an API route.

Comment: is the user_id the primary key?

Comment: Yes, but my table has a composite primary key with user_id and friend_id